# Handling glTexImage2D exceptions

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to load .PNG image and when I try to create a texture out of this image using this code

```
unsigned char *imageData1 = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width1, &height1, &noChannels1, 0); // succeeded to return data

if(imageData1) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width2, height2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData1); // raise an exception here.
}
```

The program crash and raise an exception. I figured out that I should use GL_RGB instead of GL_RGBA in the data type.

My questions is there a way to catch and handle this exceptions like this in OpenGL?

Comment: opengl API does not use exceptions for error handling. If your application crashed then it was due to fatal error and could not be recovered. Your code snippet is pretty far from [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you check the value returned by `stbi_load`? Also why do you store it in `imageData1` but then pass `imageData2` into `glTexImage2D`?

Comment: `stbi_load()` successfully returned data and yes I pass a matched `imageData` to the `glTexImage2D`, as I sad the problem was with the GL_RGB not GL_RGBA but there's no way to know this until I revised the code.

Comment: Isn't `stbi_load` parameter #3 returning image depth? If it is 4 (or 32 if it is counted in bpp) then it would be RGBA, if it is 3 (or 24) then RGB.

Comment: The error you got was most probably because you were reading outside of your memory segment. I don't think you could check for that somehow in c++. Imho this code might not even crash all the time depending on what is stored after your data in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're approaching this from the wrong angle. Instead of trying to work around the problem, you should address the actual issue. The issue at hand is, that you pass OpenGL a mismatched set of parameters and data.

OpenGL by itself *never* raises exceptions. If it it can detect that parameters are invalid it will generate an internal error and *return* from the function in which the error happened without doing something "weird".

A program crashing while inside a OpenGL function means either that there is a driver bug (very unlikely) or that there is an error in your program (likely). Crashes in `glTexImage2D` almost always are due to an out-of-bound read on the data passed. OOB reads happen if the values for width, height, border (if you use a border, which is unsupported since OpenGL-3), format and the *pixel store paramters* set with `glPixelStore` calculate to a larger size than the buffer passed into data.

So you have to make sure that you pass the right parameters to OpenGL when reading from such a buffer. As you already noticed switching to GL_RGBA prevents the crash. Now the solution is *not* to first try with GL_RGB and if that fails the other way. *In fact exceptions (also non critical ones) should **never** be relied on as some kind of program control flow decision making logic!*

STB will give you all the information you need: Width, height, number of channels; the sampling depth is always assumed 8 bits per channel-pixel. Use that information to properly parameterize OpenGL image loading. You'll have to make at least one call to `glPixelStore` to set the unpack alignment to 1 (otherwise row starts may skip; STB returns tightly packed image data). Pass width and height as they are to `glTexImage2D` and decide on the format by this

```
assert( (1 <= channels) && (4 >= channels) );
GLenum glformat;
if( opengl3 ){
    switch( channels ){
    case 1: glformat = GL_RED;  break;
    case 2: glformat = GL_RG;   break;
    case 3: glformat = GL_RGB;  break;
    case 4: glformat = GL_RGBA; break;
    }
} else {
    switch( channels ){
    case 1: glformat = GL_LUMINANCE;       break;
    case 2: glformat = GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA; break;
    case 3: glformat = GL_RGB;             break;
    case 4: glformat = GL_RGBA;            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `break;` after each of the `case` statement, otherwise `glformat` will always be equal to `GL_RGBA`. I know it's obvious, but someone might copy it without thinking too much. :)

Comment: @FilipVondrášek: whoopsie :)